# How to cite within a figure caption w/ rmarkdown native citation?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

In R Markdown, I want a figure caption with a linked citation in R Markdown native citation style `[@ref]`. However, when I insert the `[@hawking_thermodynamics_1983]` snippet at the end into the caption, it's throwing just an error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.94 ...iontextfoo [@hawking_thermodynamics_1983]}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

**Example**:

This is my code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
output: pdf_document
# bibliography: bibliography.bib
references:
- id: hawking_thermodynamics_1983
  author:
  - family: Hawking
    given: S. W.
  - family: Page
    given: Don. N.
  publisher: Communications in Mathematical Physics
  title: Thermodynamics of Black Holes in Anti-de Sitter Space.
  volume: 87
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 1983
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{example.jpg}
\caption{Captiontextfoo}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

[@hawking_thermodynamics_1983]

# Bibliography
````

with this output:

[image]

I want the citation in parentheses to appear inside the figure caption, with working link to the bibliography. The bibliography should appear automatically as usual.

How could I possibly achieve this?

---

**Notes:**

- I also tried `\[@...` or w/o brackets but didn't work.
- I tried also this `\caption{Captiontextfoo \cite{[@hawking_thermodynamics_1983]}}` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871120/6574038), but didn't work as well, shows only `[?]`.
- R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
- Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
- Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Comment: not sure about r-markdown, but in plain pandoc ships with `pandoc-citeproc` built-in. you seem to use that syntax...

Answer (score 7):

This problem appears to be fixed, and the citation can be included directly within the `fig.cap` argument:

Here is a minimal example which creates an `bib.bib` file in the same directory as the `.Rmd` file. It also includes the graphic using `includes_graphics`:

````
---
output: pdf_document
bibliography: bib.bib
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::write_bib(x = "rmarkdown", file = "bib.bib")
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "A plot [@R-rmarkdown]"}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

If this doesn't work (not entirely sure why it doesn't, but some people seem to have problems with the above), you can use text references (see [Section 2.2.4 of the **bookdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html)).

````
(ref:caption) A plot [@R-rmarkdown]

```{r echo=FALSE, fig.cap="(ref:caption)"}
plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: I was still having this problem, but your idea of text references worked.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the example of Michael Harper above, the bibliographic reference worked fine. When I changed the `plot` to `knitr::include_graphics('myfig.jpg')` it didn't work and the caption just printed `...[@R-markdown]`.

I then did both a `plot(...)` and `knitr::include_graphics('myfig.jpg')`, and when I knitted to .pdf the caption for the `plot(...)` figure was correct while the same caption for the `knitr::include_graphics('myfig.jpg')` had `...[@R-markdown]`.

So there appears to be something about loading an external figure using `knitr::include_graphics('myfig.jpg')` that breaks the bibliographic reference in a latex/pdf output. It's fine for .html or .docx - the reference is correct.

````
---
output: pdf_document
bibliography: bib.bib
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::write_bib(x = "rmarkdown", file = "bib.bib")
```   
```{r, echo=F, fig.cap="Soil profile [@R-rmarkdown]"}
plot(cars)
knitr::include_graphics('SoilProfile-Haven-1.jpg',dpi=400)
```
````

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are only producing *pdf* output, you could use `latex` directly. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

#### biblio.bib

```
@Book{xie2015,
  title = {Dynamic Documents with {R} and knitr},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year = {2015},
  edition = {2nd},
  note = {ISBN 978-1498716963},
  url = {http://yihui.name/knitr/},
}
```

#### rmarkdown.Rmd

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    citation_package: natbib
    toc: false
bibliography: biblio.bib
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
---

```{r nice-fig, fig.cap='Here is a nice figure! \\citep{xie2015}', out.width='80%', fig.asp=.75, fig.align='center', echo=FALSE}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
plot(pressure, type = 'b', pch = 19)
```
````

Produces:

[image]

Hopefully when the `rmarkdown` / `pandoc` dust settles in the near future, the original solution below will work with the latest releases once again.

#### Original

If you use the `bookdown::pdf_document2` output format, there are enhanced cross-referencing features. Placing your figure inside a code chunk also makes it easier to output as *html* if you choose multiple output formats.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
# bibliography: bibliography.bib
references:
- id: hawking_thermodynamics_1983
  author:
  - family: Hawking
    given: S. W.
  - family: Page
    given: Don. N.
  publisher: Communications in Mathematical Physics
  title: Thermodynamics of Black Holes in Anti-de Sitter Space.
  volume: 87
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 1983
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# R Markdown

```{r fig1, out.width='13cm', fig.cap='Captiontextfoo [@hawking_thermodynamics_1983]', echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("example.jpg")
```

# Bibliography
````

> For the complete package documentation, see [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/). Also, note [this](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/203) closed Github issue demonstrating your requested output.

#### Session Info

```
sessionInfo()

# R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
# 
# Matrix products: default
# 
# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252
# [3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
# [5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#  [1] compiler_3.4.3  backports_1.1.2 bookdown_0.5    magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-1
#  [6] htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.3     yaml_2.1.16     Rcpp_0.12.14    stringi_1.1.6
# [11] rmarkdown_1.8   knitr_1.17      stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.13   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Comment: Promising, but throws `Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'test71.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.111 ...ontextfoo [@hawking_thermodynamics_1983]}
                                                  \label{fig:fig1}` w/ your code, I updated my MiKTeX to 2.9.6500.and installed grom github `devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')`.

Comment: @jaySf, I couldn't replicate your error until I used a fresh environment, seems you may be caught up in the `rmarkdown` and `pandoc` bugs affecting the latest releases as a result of the pandoc 2 release. You may be better not to use the development versions until they have these squashed, although [this](https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/pandoc-2/) blog posts suggests they are at least part way there.

Comment: Sorry, there was no space to be clear enough. I meant I took a look into Github link in your answer. After your code didn't work w/ bookdown standard version I tried the dev, but no change. I'm using old pandoc version 1.19.2.1 as well and rmarkdown 1.8. I rolled back now to bookdown 0.5, but your provided code seems still not to be working. Where could be the difference in our environments?

Comment: Not working for me, produces (?) rather than (Xie, 2015) in caption.

Comment: @jaySf, I cannot replicate your problem in a fresh session, my `sessionInfo` added to my answer.

Comment: I compared both session infos, updated some packages accordingly, but still not working. I added the error message to my question. Which pandoc version do you use? On my machine `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` yields `1.19.2.1`.

Comment: @jaySf, I'm using the version packaged with *RStudio*, which happens to be the same, `1.19.2.1`.