# How to place citation exactly under a figure when there's a page-break?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

Since there's no working solution to my [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47860390/6574038), I tried to just place a citation exactly under a figure. This works until the figure experiences an automatic page-break. Then, the citation is placed where I meant to place the figure, but the figure itself appears on the next page and both get separated. Does anyone know the remedy?

Here is my code and a screenshot:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  pdf_document: default
references:
- id: hawking_thermodynamics_1983
  author:
  - family: Hawking
    given: S. W.
  - family: Page
    given: Don. N.
  publisher: Communications in Mathematical Physics
  title: Thermodynamics of Black Holes in Anti-de Sitter Space.
  volume: 87
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 1983
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lipsum}  # just used for producing example text in document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Headline
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example.png}
\caption{Example figure}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
[source: @hawking_thermodynamics_1983]

\lipsum[1-4]

## Bibliography
````

**EDIT:** This is for a *.bib version:

```
@article{hawking_thermodynamics_1983,
    title = {Thermodynamics of black holes in anti-de Sitter space},
    volume = {87},
    pages = {577--588},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {Communications in Mathematical Physics},
    author = {Hawking, S. W. and Page, Don N.},
    date = {1983-12},
}
```

[image]

Comment: The normal pandoc/rmarkdown syntax for figures is a paragraph which contains just an image; the caption is taken from the image descriptions: `[source: @hawking_thermodynamics_1983](example.png){width=10cm}`. Would that me an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the `[source: <cite>]` as part of your `figure`:

```
\begingroup
\figure[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example.png}
  \caption{Example figure}\label{fig1}
  [source: @hawking_thermodynamics_1983]
\endfigure
\endgroup
```

The above simulates the same grouping suggested by `\begin{figure}[h]`...`\end{figure}` without the explicit use of the `figure` *environment*; the Rmarkdown process skips over and assumed everything within a LaTeX environment (like `figure`) will contain LaTeX-only code, so it does not recognize the markdown syntax `[source: @<cite>]` but instead complains that `<cite>` contains an underscore, which can only be used inside math-mode.

Alternatively, if you must, add the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float) to your YAML preamble

```
header-includes:
- <other packages>
- \usepackage{float}
```

and then use the `[H]` float specifier to require the float to stay `H`ere:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example.png}
  \caption{Example figure}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
[source: @hawking_thermodynamics_1983]
```

Note that this will disrupt the regular setting of text if the float can't fit on the page.

Comment: The alternative with `float` is actually working, thanks!!! Sure the interruption—but this way I can better play around placing the figure manually until there eventually comes a working solution to my [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47860390/6574038). The first option would have been intuitive which I surely tried before but threw me an error `! Missing $ inserted.`; I should have mentioned this in my question.

Comment: @jaySf: I've supplied an option to address the issue with `[source: @<cite>]` inside the `figure` environment.

Comment: This is great stuff, exactly what I needed! It's even better than the `float` solution since there's nothing disrupted like text till the bottom of the page, footnotes etc. Even the citation is centered and in normal distance to figure caption and text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a bib file, it might be possible to use the `stackengine` package and `\cite{}`:

```
\usepackage{stackengine}

% ....

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{unnamed.png}}{\cite{hawking_thermodynamics_1983}}%
\caption{Example figure}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Though the dog is cool, it won't work. Only the [?] appears as in your figure shown.

Comment: Using a bib-file? Or using your example document?

Comment: Sure a bib file. I just had to place the `\usepackage{stackengine}` into the YAML header.

Comment: I guess you would have to use plain LaTeX to add the bibliography then to make that work.

Comment: I am getting progressively convinced by that, too!