# citing within a figure caption using r markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using R markdown with bookdown to create pdf output. As far as I can tell from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860390/how-to-cite-within-a-figure-caption-w-rmarkdown-native-citation) and this [github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/203) I am using the right syntax but it doesn't work for me I just get the "[@citation]" returned as text in the caption. 
Are there specific yaml, chunk options or packages I need to get this to work?

````
---
title: "caption citation test"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2
bibliography: Bibliography_mini.bib
---

```{r echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
 library(knitr)
 library(kableExtra)
  opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/graphics-', 
                 cache.path='cache/graphics-', 
                 fig.align='center',
                 external=TRUE,
                 echo=TRUE,
                 warning=FALSE,
                 fig.pos='H'
                )
  a4width<- 8.3
  a4height<- 11.7
```
Some text here look the citation works [@moravec1980obstacle]

```{r moravec, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="look the citation doesn't work 
[@moravec1980obstacle]"}
knitr::include_graphics("Moravec.png")
```
````

[image: Picture of output]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use text references (see [Section 2.2.4 of the **bookdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html)).

````
(ref:moravec) look the citation doesn't work [@moravec1980obstacle]

```{r moravec, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="(ref:moravec)"}
knitr::include_graphics("Moravec.png")
```
````

Answer (score 0):

A pure `latex` solution also works, which has [far more control](http://merkel.texture.rocks/Latex/natbib.php) over the citation style, although is obviously limited to pdf outputs e.g. `\citep{Bradshaw2010}`.